# Selenium: close dialog box

Tags: c#, selenium

I am trying to close the dialog box and didn't succeed.

Assuming I have the next group:

https://www.facebook.com/kidsmovie/?fref=ts

(Please login to facebook before).

1) click on "Write something on this Page..."

2) click on the photo of a camera:

[image]

(Dialog box will be opened).

How do I close this dialog after I add an image?

I have added the image by:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[text()='Add photo']/following-
sibling::div/input")).SendKeys(@"D:\myImage.png");
```

I've tried:

```
try {    
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);

    action.KeyDown(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Alt);
    action.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.F4);
}
catch (Exception ex){}


try {
    IAlert a = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
    a.Dismiss(); // or dismiss() if you want to hit 'cancel'
}
catch (Exception ex){}

try {
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.KeyDown(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Escape);
    action.Perform();
}
catch (Exception ex){}
```

I don't know if it's important or not, but the dialog can be closed by `Escape` or `alt + F4`.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: You can simulate pressing `ALT+F4` with `selenium.webdriver.common.keys` module. Something like `SendKeys(Keys.ALT+Keys.F4)`

Comment: Did you mean this one?

driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[text()='Add photo']/following-sibling::div/input")).SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Alt + OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.F4)

Comment: Actually I don't know `C#` syntax so I can't be sure... Also try `SendKeys('\ue00a'+'\ue034')`. Both solutions works in `Python`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try following code to close dialog.

```
 [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);


    private static void CloseDialog()
    {
        var handle = FindWindow(null, "Give your window caption/title here");
        SetForegroundWindow(handle);
//send alt+f4 using sendkeys method
        System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("%{F4}");
    }
```

if any issue then let me know. 
Thanks.